# scan local network (router) ip addresses with computer name in android

Tags: android, sockets, router

I saw some apps which scan local network computers (via router) and show computer name.
When I select on of them, the app connects to the selected computer.

I want to make the same thing.

My Android app(Client) is currently making connect to the Server via TCP/IP socket with IP and PORT put manually.
But, for the user-friendly interface, I want to show them a list of local computer names then them to select.

How can I make this feature?

If there is a way to obtain local computer names with each IP address, then the rest of things will be clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [Zero-configuration networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking). There are two popular implementations:

1. Microsoft UPnP
2. Apple Bounjour

Comment: I think 'zero-configuration' is the answer while I still cannot find proper examples to implement in the Android project.